# The timing issue with FPGA, after synthesizing this code, the total hold slack is a negative number

Tags: fpga, verilog, timing, vivado, synthesis

```
module teset(
    input clk,
    input rst ,
    input acc_end,
    input weight_cnt,
    output [4:0] acc_end_cnt_0

);
    reg [4:0] acc_end_cnt;      

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
    if (rst == 1'b0)
        acc_end_cnt <= 0;
    else  if (acc_end || (weight_cnt == 0 && acc_end_cnt != 0))
        acc_end_cnt <= (acc_end_cnt >= 16) ? 0 : acc_end_cnt + 1;
end

assign acc_end_cnt_0 = acc_end_cnt;

endmodule
```

This is the code, The function is to update the acc_end_cnt ,when I synthesize in Vivado，the total hold slack is negative，

here are the time.xdc

```
create_clock -period 5 -name clk  [get_ports clk]
```

Here are the design timing summary

[image: design timing summary]

[image: intra-path-clock]

It's strange why the total hold slack is negative when synthesizing, but it becomes positive after implementation

[image: implementation]

Comment: It appears you have just a little too much combinatorial logic to execute in the 200MHz clock period. Assuming 'rst' is just a power on reset, i.e. not used dynamically at runtime, then it would be more efficient to remove it entirely from your process and just initialize acc_end_cnt to zero when it is instantiated  ( reg [4:0] acc_reg_cnt = 0; ). This may be enough to get your timing to squeak by. Also, although Vivado would be lame to not figure it itself, the term (acc_end_cnt >= 16) simplifies to a single bit (acc_end_cnt[4]).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Question/answer on the Xilinx/AMD support page is very similar to this one.

The last answer at [negative-slack-after-synthesis](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00007FSYxRSAX/negative-slack-after-synthesis?language=en_US):

> Vivado synthesis delay estimates for both cells and routing is quite pessimistic and inaccurate. I almost never pay attention to synthesis timing report given that the synthesis numbers are withing 20-30% of the period you are working with. The first somewhat usable timing values come at place_design stage.